# How to include files with variables in twig?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

How do I `include` files with `set` variables in twig?

In my main twig file:

```
{% include navbar_content.html.twig %}
```

In `navbar_content.html.twig` :

```
{% set logo %}
1
{% endset %}

{% set left %}
2
{% endset %}

{% set right %}
3
{% endset %}
```

But these variables are not been passed.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ^ Can't be done in pure `Twig`, you should do something like the work around that OP posted as answer

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
{% set logo = 1 %}
{% set left = 2 %}
{% set right = 3 %}
```

Comment: Yes but in the syntax I show above. It works if in the same file, but I need them separate.